# java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, массивы, исключения

Имею массив типа `Object` и нужно переделать его в массив `String`.

Делаю это вот так:

```
public static String[] convertorObjectToString(Object[] objArr)
{
    String [] strArr = Arrays.copyOf(objArr, objArr.length, String[].class);
    return strArr;
}
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Что не так?

Comment: А у тебя все элементы массива являются String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что исходный массив не весь состоит из String.

Можно сделать надежнее :

```
String[] strArr = new String[objArr.length]
for(int i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
 strArr[i] = String.valueOf(objArr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А так нельзя. Если у тебя в исходном массиве хранятся Object и их фактический тип НЕ String, то их нельзя положить в массив String[]. 
Можно конечно вызывать у исходного массива метод toString() как это сделал @Andrew Bystrov.

Comment: Будем честны, не у массива, а у каждого элемента из этого массива;)

Comment: да, точно. но у массива toString вызывать тож нормально XD. А можно ещё Arrays.toString(Object[] obj) а затем строку поделить split() , извращаться можно до вечера